# Is there Android API to control global http proxy?

Tags: android

I am looking for Android API which will allow to control global http proxy on Android.

I am not interested in solutions which involve rooting a device.

However, I am ok with some API which works only on latest version of OS (if such API exist).

Comment: I'd be very surprised if any such functions exist-  it would be a massive security hole.  All of your apps would suddenly be open to man in the middle attacks by the server you set.  Google isn't that stupid.

Comment: @Gabe: Generally speaking you are right. However, this security hole will only be applicable to http (not https) traffic. And http traffic in most cases could be treated as insecure by default.

Comment: Victor, put a bounty on this and I'll post up some code that will let you set a HTTP proxy on the entire device without requiring root.

Comment: @Simon: I think it's kind-of rude request. The whole idea of SO is open sharing of the information. Bounty are used in exceptional cases when an __asker__ is willing to reward somebody (vs. __answered__ thinking that the answer is too valuable).

Comment: I have found a way, which I can describe. But if an exam is required it would take some time. I will post a description of a method that would work a little later.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no API for this. You need to ask your user to apply the change if that's necessary, but you cannot do that yourself from code w/o rooting